# Makefile not using correct constants?

Tags: c, makefile, c-preprocessor

I'm having some trouble with a Makefile today. Here's the relevant code:

I have the following directory structure:

```
/bin
/obj
/headers
    config.h
    test-config.h
/lib
/src
/test
    /src
    /bin
    /obj
    Makefile
 Makefile
```

The root directory is where my application code exists, and the test directory is where I am writing my test code. The main Makefile is pretty normal and compiles everything as expected. The Makefile in the test directory `mv`'s the `config.h` file to a `.bak` file and then moves the `test-config.h` to be a new `config.h`, then compiles the main code, moves everything in the root obj/ into the test's obj folder. It then proceeds to compile the tests.

My problem is that a constant in the primary config file is still appearing in my code. So I assume that something is going wrong with the config files and compiling the root level code. Here's my test Makefile:

```
#Configurations and setup
CC = cc
CFLAGS = -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -I../headers -Isrc
LINKFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)
LIBS = ../lib/wolkykim-qdecoder-63888fc/src/libqdecoder.a

OBJECTS := $(patsubst src/%.c,obj/%.o,$(wildcard src/*.c))
TARGETS := $(patsubst src/%.c,bin/%.out,$(wildcard src/*.c))

#internals are non cgi scripts that we need
INTERNAL := $(patsubst src/internal/%.c,obj/%.o,$(wildcard ../src/internal/*.c))

#Commands to help test and run programs:    
valgrind = valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20 --track-fds=yes

.PHONY: clean 

all: ${TARGETS} 

$(TARGETS): copyobjects $(OBJECTS)
    ${CC} ${LINKFLAGS} -g -o $@ $(patsubst bin/%.out, obj/%.o, $@ ) $(INTERNAL) ${LIBS}

clean:
    rm -f obj/*.o ${TARGETS}
    rm -f ../obj/*.o

copyobjects:
    -mv ../headers/config.h ../headers/config.h.bak
    -mv ../headers/test-config.h ../headers/config.h
    rm -f obj/*.o 
    cd ../ && make && cd test
    cp ../obj/*.o obj/
    -mv ../headers/config.h ../headers/test-config.h
    -mv ../headers/config.h.bak ../headers/config.h

$(OBJECTS): obj/%.o : src/%.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c -o $@ $<

test: $(TARGETS)
    -@rm /tmp/data-test || true #remove any test data created so far
    $(valgrind) ./$<
```

The troublesome define is:

```
//config.h
#ifndef DATA_DIR
#define DATA_DIR "/path/to/program/data/"
#endif

//test-config.h
#undef DATA_DIR
#ifndef DATA_DIR
#define DATA_DIR "/tmp/data-test/"
#endif
```

The entire project's source code for your inspection can be found here: https://github.com/EJEHardenberg/pChat

I'm quite confused as to why it's not working and tried googling for when the preprocessor is ran in coordination with a Makefile, but I couldn't find anything that seemed relevant.

My test program is the following:

```
//test-init.c
#include "testp.h"

int main(){
    pci_init();
    /* There should now be a DATA_DIR directory and a users index */

    assert( directory_exists(DATA_DIR) == 1 );
    assert( file_exists(DATA_DIR USERS_INDEX) == 1 );
}

//testp.h
#ifndef __TEST_H__
#define __TEST_H__

/* Set the Data Directory to the test Directory */
#undef DATA_DIR
#define DATA_DIR "/tmp/data-test/"
#include "base.h"
#include <assert.h>

#endif
```

The assert fails:
test-init.out: src/test-init.c:7: main: Assertion `directory_exists("/tmp/data-test/") == 1' failed.

Where directory exists is a function that tests the obvious and returns 0 or 1

### Edit with makefile output:

```
user@Turing ~/Programming/C/pChat/test $ make test
mv ../headers/config.h ../headers/config.h.bak
mv ../headers/test-config.h ../headers/config.h
rm -f obj/*.o 
cd ../ && make clean all && cd test
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Programming/C/pChat'
rm -f obj/*.o bin/heartbeat.cgi
cc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -I./headers -c -o obj/heartbeat.o src/heartbeat.c
cc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -I./headers -c src/internal/data-manip.c -o obj/data-manip.o 
cc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -I./headers -c src/internal/fasthash.c -o obj/fasthash.o 
cc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -I./headers -o bin/heartbeat.cgi  obj/heartbeat.o  obj/data-manip.o  obj/fasthash.o lib/wolkykim-qdecoder-63888fc/src/libqdecoder.a
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Programming/C/pChat'
cp ../obj/*.o obj/
mv ../headers/config.h ../headers/test-config.h
mv ../headers/config.h.bak ../headers/config.h
cc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -I../headers -Isrc -c -o obj/test-init.o src/test-init.c
cc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -I../headers -Isrc -g -o bin/test-init.out  obj/test-init.o ../src/internal/data-manip.c ../src/internal/fasthash.c ../lib/wolkykim-qdecoder-63888fc/src/libqdecoder.a
rm: cannot remove `/tmp/data-test': No such file or directory
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20 --track-fds=yes ./bin/test-init.out
==4083== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4083== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4083== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4083== Command: ./bin/test-init.out
==4083== 
Could not run init for Private Chat. Could not create directory: /home/user/Programming/pChat/data/
test-init.out: src/test-init.c:7: main: Assertion `directory_exists("/tmp/data-test/") == 1' failed.
==4083== 
==4083== FILE DESCRIPTORS: 3 open at exit.
==4083== Open file descriptor 2: /dev/pts/0
==4083==    <inherited from parent>
==4083== 
==4083== Open file descriptor 1: /dev/pts/0
==4083==    <inherited from parent>
==4083== 
==4083== Open file descriptor 0: /dev/pts/0
==4083==    <inherited from parent>
==4083== 
==4083== 
==4083== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4083==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4083==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 502 bytes allocated
==4083== 
==4083== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4083== 
==4083== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4083== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
make: *** [test] Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: I can get it to work if I use the `-DDATA_DIR="\"/tmp/datatest\"" in my compiler, but I would really like it to use the test-config as it seems like it's not using it at all. Even though I am including test-config in the test-init.h file.

Comment: What compilations need `test-config.h` instead of `config.h`? Because right now you appear to explicitly attempt to re-run make in the root directory to compile with that in effect but that may or may not actually do anything depending on whether make things the objects need to be recompiled (and they don't depend on `config.h` that I can see so that changing won't trigger it). What output do you get from your run of make about this?

Comment: I stopped including `test-config.h` in the testp.h file, and am just using `config.h` since the files are moved around. The particular file that contains these functions that I'm testing is data-manip.c, whose .h file includes "base.h" which in turn includes "config.h"

Comment: @EtanReisner editted with makefile output

Comment: That appears to be getting the correct definition of `DATA_DIR` doesn't it? My point about ordering before was the fact that compilation of `test-init.o` and the linking of `test-init.out` happen after the header files are restored. Oh, I see, you are setting that manually in `testp.h` at this point.

Comment: The test file has the correct `DATA_DIR` but the `data-manip.c` functions have been compiled with the wrong `DATA_DIR`. In data-manip, the init function uses DATA_DIR as an argument to creating directories and such. I threw sleeps into the makefile between each command just to make sure it wasn't a timing issue and still got the same problem.

Comment: also I am running `cd ../ && make clean all && cd test` shouldn't the clean take care of that? or perhaps the headers are loaded only once?

Comment: Assuming clean removes the objects, yes. And that final `&& cd test` is useless. Also you could use make's `-C` argument instead of manually using `cd`. Also, are you duplicating all the .c files from `/src` in `/test/src`?

Comment: I am not duplicating the .c files from /src -> /test/src, only the /obj/* -> test/obj/, and clean does remove the objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it. This is how:

In my Makefile's copyobjects target I had the following:

```
copyobjects:
    -mv ../headers/config.h ../headers/config.h.bak
    -mv ../headers/test-config.h ../headers/config.h
    rm -f obj/*.o 
    cd ../ && make && cd test
    cp ../obj/*.o obj/
    -mv ../headers/config.h ../headers/test-config.h
    -mv ../headers/config.h.bak ../headers/config.h

test: $(TARGETS)
    -@rm /tmp/data-test || true #remove any test data created so far
    $(valgrind) ./$<
```

Which moved the configuration file around as I expected it to. This is what's working now:

```
copyobjects:
    -mv ../headers/config.h ../headers/config.h.bak
    -mv ../headers/test-config.h ../headers/config.h
    rm -f obj/*.o 
    cd ../ && make && cd test
    cp ../obj/*.o obj/

test: $(TARGETS)
    -@rm /tmp/data-test || true #remove any test data created so far
    $(valgrind) ./$<
    -@mv ../headers/config.h ../headers/test-config.h
    -@mv ../headers/config.h.bak ../headers/config.h
```

The problem seems to be that the defines are not "weaved" into the actual binaries until the linking time, so it doesn't matter if I compile into object files with header X or header Y, it only matters when I link against it.

So in short: `#define`'s are actually replaced at the link stage of compilation by `cc` and not the compile stage (what I had originally thought) I looked through `man cc` looking for something saying this, but that man page is **very** long. And I find conflicting evidence [here](http://www.herongyang.com/Computer-History/C-Program-Compilation-and-Execution-Process.html) saying that the preprocesser runs on source before linking. BUT: [at this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html) 
(which I trust way more) it says

> Whether you use the preprocessor by way of gcc or cpp, the compiler driver is run first. This program's purpose is to translate your command into invocations of the programs that do the actual work. Their command line interfaces are similar but not identical to the documented interface, and may change without notice.

<s>So, the compiler is ran first (getting me my .o files) and then the defines. If this is not the case please comment below with a proper reference.</s>

As commented below, the preprocessor is ran before the compiler and linker. The real problem was in the order of my Makefile's configuration and dependencies.

Comment: [The preprocessor is executed at translation phase 4, before the compilation. The result of preprocessing is a single file which is then passed to the actual compiler.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor)

Comment: this is for cpp, do you have any idea if it's the same as cc? (I use cc as my compiler since it's just a c project and not a cpp project)

Comment: cc usually simply is a link to gcc, anyway what I linked you above [is the same for C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor) or C++, regardless of what compiler you use.

Comment: awesome. Thanks. I just want to be sure so that misinformation isn't spread through my answer. So I am right that the defines occur before the linking of the object files together then yes?

Comment: Operations are in this order : Preprocessor -> Compilation -> Linking. So, this statement "_So, the compiler is ran first (getting me my .o files) and then the defines._" is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I've editted the answer a bit and crossed out the incorrect statement.